# How to display an appropriate response on <MaterialTable> when the search returns no results?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using in React the table from https://material-table.com/
But I'm running a data search on promise. If the search doesn't return any results, the table will be loaded forever... My idea is to show some message. How can I do this optimally?

```
 <MaterialTable
    title="Documents"
    columns={cols}
    data={query =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let url = global.url_base+'service'
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                        search: query.search,
                        pageSize: query.pageSize,
                        page: (query.page + 1),
                        id: sessionStorage.getItem('id')
            }),
            headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
            })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            resolve({
            data: result.data,
            page: result.page - 1,
            totalCount: result.total,
            })
        })
    })
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch your data someplace else, eg. in componentDidMount(), where you set it as a state variable. Then, in your MaterialTable just put `data={(this.state.response) ? response : 'Your error message'}` or, if this table doesn't consume string as data, just toggle rendering the whole MaterialTable and your error message.

Comment: It didn't work for me because I couldn't find the variable that contains the search. 
for example:
 componentDidMount() { 
    console.log(this.tableRef.current.state.searchText);
    } 
In this case this.tableRef.current.state.searchText is never updated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MaterialTable, but I found this: `onSearchChange`, so I guess you could do `onSearchChange=this.setState({myQuery: query.search})`.  About getting the query - look here: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/857 That's more or less what I had in mind: fetch data outside of the table and render conditionally based on the response.